# Focus window by mouse hover

Tags: mouse

Hello I was moved to ElementaryOS from i3wm with Ubuntu and I am accustomed that the windows gain focus when I hover it by mouse instead of click.

For me, with multi-monitors, that's really useful.

How can I setup this behavior in ElementaryOS??
Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-mode 'sloppy'
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do it via graphical interface, which presents additional options, by simply installing GNOME Tweaks (available by searching within the AppCenter). From here, simply find the 'Windows' tab at the bottom of the panel and review the options in the 'Window Focus' section. You can choose 'Sloppy', 'Secondary-Click' and/or 'Raise Windows When Focused'. Hope that's some help!